# Is there any image format that allows the opening of an annotation box?

Tags: image, graph, annotations, interactive, box

Let's speak about graphs.

I know that a real interactive annotation can be done only with different stat-packages like R-shiny and similar.

But my question here is much easier and related to the image file format.
I would like to add something like a comment box or something related to a specific dot on an image (a plot in my case) that could be open with a mouse drag or click.

I don't want to know how to do it, or which softwares do I need.
The only question is, is there any image format that could allow the insert of this kind of things? gif, png, ... ?

Something similar to this, shown with a mouse click:
[image: My image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The [TIFF file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TIFF) allows you to store multiple frames in one file.
You could store a page with annotations and one without, or a page for each annotation.

[Here](http://www.nightprogrammer.org/development/multipage-tiff-example-download-test-image-file/) is an example of a multi-page tiff.

This is what it looks like on Windows Photo Viewer when going to page 2:

[image: Multi-frame TIFF page 2 in Windows Photo Viewer]